# First Child List Item Not Aligned in Chrome (Mac/Windows)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

**JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UXA5Q/**

I have the following HTML code:

```
      <ul class="advisorlist">
           <li>                     
              <div class="employee">
                   <address>
                       <a title="E-mail John Doe" href="http://www.example.com/employee.html" rel="nofollow" class="email"><strong>John Doe</strong></a>
                       <br><em>Academic Advisor</em>
                      <br>Phone: 540-351-5555                           
                      <br>Fax: 540-351-5555                             
                   </address>                                           
               </div>                                          
            </li>                                      
            <!-- etc -->
       </ul>
```

And the following CSS Code:

```
ul.advisorlist {
    clear:both;
    list-style: none;
}
ul.advisorlist li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 10px 10px 0 10px;
    width: 140px;
    min-height: 200px;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 200px;
}
```

The first item in the list is unaligned in Chrome on Mac/Windows. Chromium, FF, Safari, IE, etc. show all the list items correctly.

[image: Image of non aligned first child]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing `clear:both;` on `ul.advisorlist`.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/UXA5Q/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

`clear: both` means no floating elements may be adjacent to an earlier floating box on either side.

> The clear property indicates which sides of an element's box(es) may not be adjacent to an earlier floating box.

http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/clear

Some more very detailed info on `clear`: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#flow-control

Remove it and you're looking good.

Also, you have a bunch of css which doesn't do much! Check out this [jsFiddle fork](http://jsfiddle.net/tpPxL/) I put together.

Comment: Thanks for the info on clear!

The other stuff is useful, for ex. the min-height is for images in those list items, but I stripped down the list items heavily for this question.

Answer (score 0):

.remove the clear:both from the parent of li and add overflow: hidden to the ul

Comment: Already accepted an answer. But why `overflow: hidden`? I'm intrigued

Answer (score 0):

```
li {
list-style-position: inside;
}
```

worked for me. Thank you all for your efforts!